# Write url request output to a csv in Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to write the response out into a csv. Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time

site = 'url'

with open('receipts_10.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:

        response = requests.post(site, params={'appReceiptNum':row})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
        status = soup.find("h4")
        statusString = status.text
```

I've opened up a csv and now I want to overwrite that same csv with the output:

```
        print(statusString)
```

As you can see I'm only printing out the response in the console, but need it in  a .csv instead. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to *write* you use the `writer()` not the `reader()`.  And you need to open the file for *writing*, `'w'` not reading.

Comment: Oh sorry I read the file first and now I'm trying to send the output to the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a csv writer.

Something like

```
with open('receipts_10.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    outfile = 'somefile.csv'
    ofile = open(outfile,"wb")
    writer = csv.writer(ofile,delimiter=";")

    for row in reader:       
        response = requests.post(site, params={'appReceiptNum':row})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
        status = soup.find("h4")
        statusString = status.text
        writer.writerow(statusString)
```

You might of course have to do some formatting of the status string, change delimiter, quoting, or other options in the writer. Use the Python documetation for  the csv library to guide you.  But that's the basic principle.

If you are actually not reading anything in from a csv file, you don't need the reader of course.

Comment: I ended up with: IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: You'll have to look at what is in your status string and see if it is writeable to a csv file  [e.g looks like a list of strings]  and if not, do appropriate reformatting.

Comment: IndentationError is Syntax check your tabs/spacing... Everything under with should be tabbed